# Column remains empty when using .map() with dictionary in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary with `key:value` pairs that I am reading from Github as a raw text file.

Dict-structure:

```
{"Absetzung":50,
"Amtsantritt":42,
"Amtseinführung":41,
"Aufenthalt":20,
"Aufnahme":20,
"Aufschwörung":20}
```

Column names in dataframe:

```
column_names = ["factoid_ID",
                "pers_ID",
                "pers_name",
                "alternative_names",
                "event_type",
                "event_after-date",
                "event_before-date",
                "event_start",
                "event_end",
                "event_date",
                "pers_title",
                "pers_function",
                "place_name",
                "inst_name",
                "rel_pers",
                "source_quotations",
                "additional_info",
                "comment",
                "info_dump",
                "source_combined",
                "event_value",
                "source",
                "source_site"]
```

After converting them to valid dictionaries, I can access the data by calling a key. But I cannot use the `.map()` function for dataframes.

The dataframe column to which I want to assign the dictionary values remains empty. Perhaps an issue is that the key comes from a different column.

Here is my code:

```
# importing the module
import requests
import ast

master = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/###/###/main/###/Event_value_dict.txt"
req = requests.get(master)
req = req.text
print(req)

# reconstructing the data as a dictionary
event_value_dict = ast.literal_eval(req)
print(type(event_value_dict))

# add event values from dict to data frame

try:
    test = event_value_dict["Aufschwörung"] # random test if valid dict
    print("Value for chosen key: ", test)
except:
    print("Invalid dict structure!")
   
df3['event_value'] = df3['event_type'].map(event_value_dict) # optional: na_action='ignore'
df3.sort_values(by =['event_after-date','event_start','event_before-date', 'event_end', 'event_value'])

display(df3)
```

Comment: Hard to say for sure since we can't know what data you are using

Comment: Why does the `.map` happen only if an exception is encountered?

Comment: Sorry, lost my indentation when copying the code. Will fix.

Comment: What do you see in `event_value` after the `map`? It should be `NaN` if no matching value is found in the mapping dict.

Comment: btw, you call `sort_values` without `inplace=True` and without assigning the result anywhere: you probably want to do one or other of those. But that isn't directly related to your problem.

Comment: Yes, I saw ```NaN``` in event_value. That got me thinking and I went all the way up in my code to where I used the ```groupby``` function. I did not add ```as_index=False```, which messed up the event_type column. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments to my questions above, I was able to fix the problem by reviewing my use of the `groupby` function further up in the code.

Not adding `as_index=False` "merged" the columns I was grouping by on the same values vertically, so values from the dictionary could no longer be found in the `event_type` column.

Here is the updated code:

```
grouped_df = df2.groupby(['pers_name', 'event_type', "pers_function", "pers_title", "inst_name", "place_name"], as_index=False).agg(
                                                         {'event_start': 'min',
                                                          "event_after-date":'min',
                                                          "event_before-date":'max',
                                                          "event_end":'max',
                                                          "factoid_ID":list,
                                                          "alternative_names":list,
                                                          "pers_ID":list,
                                                          "rel_pers":list,
                                                          "source_quotations":list,
                                                          "additional_info":list,
                                                          "comment":list,
                                                          "info_dump":list,
                                                          "source_combined":list,
                                                          "event_value":list
                                                          })

display(grouped_df)
```